# What it mean by the API when it says the interface's method returns something?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, type-inference, flatmap

I understand that we cannot instantiate an interface but while doing the tutorial from a book regarding `Streams`, I got confused.

I will just use the portion of code to highlight the part which I don't understand.

```
// count occurences of each word in a Stream<String> sorted by word
    Map<String, Long> wordCounts =
        Files.lines(Paths.get("Chapter2Paragraph.txt"))
             .map(line -> line.replaceAll("(?!')\\p{P}", ""))
             .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line))
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

For the method `flatMap`, when clicked upon in the API, it says it:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream. (If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)

So what does it mean by that? I kinda understand what it does but I simply don't understand how it works behind the scenes. Does it return an Object when the API mentions returns in this case or does it mean that it replaces the current stream? Additionally, when using `Streams`, does the compiler actually creates an Object of these elements and then terminates when it's done?

Additionally, from the code above, I just want to make sure that I'm correct.
When you have a `Map<String, Long> wordCounts` variable, does it mean that at the end of the stream termination, the end result has to follow exactly the type inference?

Comment: Are you asking what the docs mean, or what it does behind the scenes? Because those are two nearly orthogonal questions.

Comment: Reading this question, I'm kinda glad I learned about Python generators before I moved to Java version 8.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wish to know what is going on behind the scenes and is it better for one to learn Python first before attempting any other languages in order to understand better?

Comment: Your question is about something that is explicitly unspecified. The method may return a new `Stream` instance or modify an existing one (and return it). All you have to know, is, that you have to use the returned instance. The compiler does none of the things you asked. The compiler translates your source code to bytecode.

Comment: @Scorpiorian83. No, Python won't help you much here if you don't already have a background in the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have analyzed the situation mostly correctly, but perhaps you are hazy about some of the intermediate steps.

You have a chain of methods that are called on the return value of the previous method in the chain. The return value of the final method (`collect`) is stored in the `Map` named `wordCounts`. Disregarding exactly what the methods do and what they return (just for a moment), this is standard behavior when you call a chain of methods like that.

The generic type of the map is determined by `String::toLowerCase` and `Collectors.counting()` in the final method call. The former specifies the key type to be `String` and the latter specifies the values to be `Long`. If, as an example, you had used `String::length` as the key instead, you would have gotten a map of type `Map<Integer, Long>` instead, which would have counted the number of occurrences of words with a given length.

Going back to the sequence of function calls, it can be broken down as follows:

1. [`Files.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) creates a [`Stream<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of the lines in a file. Since the result is a stream, you can now call...
2. [`Stream.map(Function<String, String>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) transforms the input stream of strings into another stream of strings using the call to `line.replaceAll(...)`.
3. The stream of edited lines now gets [`Stream.flatMap(Function<String, Stream<String>>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to it to split the lines into words and return a single continuous stream. Remember that `pattern.splitAsStream` will be applied to each line in sequence, and so will return as many streams as there are lines. `Stream.flatMap` takes all those streams and strings them out into a single continuous stream.

   Note that the whole purpose of encapsulation is that you don't have to know exactly how the process works under the hood. You only need to know what the final result is (in this case a `Stream<String>`). You should be able to swap an implementation that reads all the streams into an underlying collection up-front and returns a stream from that with one that opens each stream lazily as elements are processed without having to worry about what is really happening.
4. Now that you have a `Stream<String>` of words in the file, you apply what is called the terminal operation: `Stream.collect(Collector<String, String, Map<String, Long>>)`. The collector is created by [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function<String, String>, Supplier<Map<String, String>>, Collector<String, String, Long>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-). This creates a collector that groups the input stream into sub-streams according to the key returned by the classifier `Function` (`String.toLowerCase()`) and passes it into a "downstream" collector to do the actual accumulation on each sub-stream. The resulting accumulation is stored into the map returned by the `Supplier` (`TreeMap::new`). The downstream `Collector` is created by [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--), which just counts the number of elements in each stream.

I have expanded all the generic types in this description to make it easier to follow along and see the kinds of objects that result from each step.

On a more general note, streams in Java have two types of operations: intermediate and terminal. The stream comes from a source (in this case your file). All the intermediate operations (1-3) turn one stream into another stream. The input and output types are always clearly defined, as I have shown above, just like for any other operation. The terminal operation is one that returns a single value of some sort based on the stream. In your case, you count the word frequencies and stash them into a `Map`. This is pretty well documented in the [`java.util.stream` package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Answer (score 2):

`flapMap()` turns each element into a stream (of any type). The streams are concatenated together to make one big stream.

In your example, the entire file is streamed (as one stream) after each line is split on the pattern (not specified in the question).